# Macro Speed Improvement

Tags: vba, macos, excel

I have written a VBA program to clean up and sort many lines of data on to separate sheets. I am quite happy with it, and it's doing exactly what I need it to do. Unfortunately it can take up to ten minutes to run, as there is around 650,000 lines of data. While stepping through the macros individually, I have determined that the macros that actually search, cut then paste data onto a separate sheet are causing the problem. Does anyone have any tips on what I can do to improve this? I will leave a macro here for you guys to take a look at.

So you know, this is what she does in order: Delete unnecessary data, remove duplicates, sort into separate sheets, then count like addresses.

I have a "RUN" macro that a "Start" button is linked to, to call all macros in the necessary order. In this macro I disable calculation and screen updating, then enable when all macros have completed.

As I mentioned here is one of my sorting macros:

```
Sub CorpSheet() 'Moves corporate memberships to new sheet
    Dim Check As Range, r As Long, lastrow2 As Long, LastRow As Long
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LastRow = Worksheets("PASTE DATA HERE").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastrow2 = Worksheets("Corporate").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If lastrow2 = 1 Then lastrow2 = 0

    For r = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Range("E" & r).Value > 0 Then
            Rows(r).Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Corporate") _
                .Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
            lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
        Else:
        End If
    Next r

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help that you can provide is appreciated!

Comment: As a first step you could turn off Screen Updating, Events , Status Bar and Recalculation

Comment: I’m not sure I get why you’re doing this line `If lastrow2 = 1 Then lastrow2 = 0`. Does that just force it not to run or does it run into negatives until it gives up?

Comment: Is this on a Macintosh? - as per the [tag:macos] tag you chose?  ..or perhaps you meant to choose [tag:macros] - which is *also* not a correct tag for this.  Hover your mouse over the tags to see descriptions..

Comment: The `Else` does nothing.  Also I'm not sure why you have `Application.ScreenUpdating` commented-out if you're trying to improve speed.

Comment: I'd also remove the `Else:` which does absolutely nothing. Not your problem, but there seems to be an `End If` missing

Comment: The individual `.Cut` operations are killing you. Can you sort the sheet to get them into a contiguous range?

Comment: Filter the sheet on ColE >0 - copy/paste the remaining rows to Corporate. Then delete the visible rows from the filtered table.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input...and Ashlee I'm sorry about that. I had the screen updating commented out because I am running them in my master, or "RUN" macro. The Else: and lastrow2 lines are from me playing around when writing the program. I forgot to remove them, but the program works with them there. Just sloppy, my apologies. Finally, that's what I thought, .Cut was killing me. Thank you guys so much for all of your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that would save a lot of time is only doing 1 copy. `UNION` the rows then copy them to the other sheet and delete them from the original in 1 step:

```
Sub CorpSheet() 'Moves corporate memberships to new sheet
    Dim Check As Range, r As Long, lastrow2 As Long, LastRow As Long

    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    LastRow = Worksheets("PASTE DATA HERE").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastrow2 = Worksheets("Corporate").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If lastrow2 = 1 Then lastrow2 = 0

    For r = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Range("E" & r).Value > 0 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Rows(r)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, Rows(r))
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    rng.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Corporate").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
    rng.Delete xlUp

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Then you can clean some things up a bit, fully qualify your ranges, and remove some other unnecessary code:

```
Sub CorpSheet() 'Moves corporate memberships to new sheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rw In Worksheets("PASTE DATA HERE").UsedRange
        If rw.Range("E1").Value > 0 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = rw.EntireRow
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, rw.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    rng.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Corporate").Range("A" & _
        Worksheets("Corporate").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

    rng.Delete xlUp

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Filter the sheet on ColE >0 - copy/paste the remaining rows to Corporate. Then delete the visible rows from the filtered table

```
Sub Faster()

    Dim rngSrc As Range

    Set rngSrc = Sheet1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    rngSrc.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">0"
    rngSrc.Copy Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    rngSrc.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    rngSrc.AutoFilter

End Sub
```